# How to open Visual Studio with "Attach to Unity" - easy and quick

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

If I try to open generated Unity solution (*.sln file) - I don't see option `Attach to Unity`

[image: Attach to Unity option]

Is it possible to open solution with option `Attach to Unity` without manipulation with Unity Editor itself, preferences and so on ?

Just by **open solution file** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES !**

Only by 2 steps:

1. Inside Unity just click (or open) to any *.cs file - it will start your Visual Studio with proper parameters

[image]

2. After that just open your solution - and **magic happened**